# El plugin gpp-compiler de atom no me funciona

Tags: c++, atom-editor

acabo de empezar a programar en C++ en el IDE de Atom y estoy usando el plugin de gpp-compiler.

A la hora de compilar me sale este error

[image: Error a la hora de compilar]

No entiendo por que me sale ya que he instalado el MinGW y añadirlo al PATH

Gracias

Comment: ¿En la barra de herramientas te sale una opcion para configurar el boton de cerrar?

Comment: Te refieres en atom? Que quieres decir?

Comment: . Me disculpo pense que atom era un IDE como Dev-Cpp.

Comment: No pasa nada, en Atom vas añadiendo plugins según en qué lenguaje vayas a programar

Comment: Intenta quitarle los espacio en el nombre del archivo que estas compilando.